# Command pattern design in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have more or less implemented the command pattern in my Spring Boot application. I still have some doubts and would like to get second opinion on them.

I have a `CommandFactory` which - when given a command code - returns an instance of command object that implements `Command` functional interface and has a single method called `execute`.

Here's an example of use:

- **PersonService:**

```
public Person addChildToPerson(Long personId, Long childId) {
    // acquire a person object from the database given an id
    Person person = (Person) commandFactory.create(GET_PERSON_BY_ID, personId).execute();
    // do the same with child
    Child child = (Child) commandFactory.create(GET_CHILD_BY_ID, childId).execute();
    return (Person) commandFactory.create(ADD_CHILD_TO_PERSON, person, child).execute();
}
```

Now here's the code of a `AddChildToPersonCommand` class that is responsible for attaching the child to the person and persisting it in the database.

- **AddChildToPersonCommand:**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddChildToPersonCommand implements Command {

     // declare needed components for performing the command
     private final ChildRepository childRepository;
     private final Person person;
     private final Child child;

     @Override
     public Person execute() {
         // some logic
     }
}
```

Now, my doubts are mainly concerned with the "declared components" for the execution of a command. I'm unsure whether it's a better practice to operate on the actual objects that have been already retrieved using other commands (in the example: `GetPersonByIdCommand` & `GetChildByIdCommand`) or to just give the `AddChildToPersonCommand` the IDs and let it take care of the rest.

On the one hand, it seems a better approach to operate on the objects as it decreases the responsibilites of `AddChildToPersonCommand`.

On the other hand, though, the **PersonService**'s methods may end up really big when the logic to-be-performed is not as trivial as in this example.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't see any advantage to using Commands here; plus the fact the outputs require type casting would be absolutely a nonstarter for me.

Comment: OK, thank you. I've decided to implement commands for learning purposes mainly, but I think that they might come in handy when the application grows more. And you're right about type casting, this actually is a big code smell and I should work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the casts if you capture the return type via generic type parameters. E.g.:

```
interface Command<T> {
    class Id<T> {}

    T execute();
}

public static final Command.Id<Person> GET_PERSON_BY_ID = new Command.Id<>();
public static final Command.Id<Child> GET_CHILD_BY_ID = new Command.Id<>();
public static final Command.Id<Person> ADD_CHILD_TO_PERSON = new Command.Id<>();

public static class CommandFactory {
    private <T> Command<T> get(Command.Id<T> commandId, Object... args) {
        // Implement...
    }
}

private static final CommandFactory commandFactory = new CommandFactory();

public static class AddChildToPersonCommand implements Command<Person> {
    // ...
}

public Person addChildToPerson(Long personId, Long childId) {
    // acquire a person object from the database given an id
    Person person = commandFactory.get(GET_PERSON_BY_ID, personId).execute();
    // do the same with child
    Child child = commandFactory.get(GET_CHILD_BY_ID, childId).execute();
    return commandFactory.get(ADD_CHILD_TO_PERSON, person, child).execute();
}
```

TBH it's not clear what benefit you're deriving from the command approach, and it seems to add unnecessary complexity as well as being cumbersome and somewhat expensive in terms of object creation. For example, it would be cleaner if AddChildToPersonCommand only stored the ChildRepository as a field, and the Person and Child were passed as arguments to the execute method.

Eithr way, I think this question would be more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. It might be more suited to the code review now that I think about it. Anyways, I've implemented this pattern for learning purposes and haven't really considered the memory complexity that it brings. Thank you for reminding me of that, althoguh - as I mentioned - the project is rather academic. I also use microservices in the project probably making the command pattern even less usable, but to be honest, I quite like this approach. Also, thanks a lot for the generic type parameters solution.